# Forecolor from parent doesn't work with groupbox text and combobox

Tags: winforms

I am currently trying to change the forecolor of my Winforms vb.net application.
So I change the forecolor of my main Form and all the controls inside must get the new value if the forecolor has not been set otherwise (by ambient property functionality).

It doesn't work with must of the controls but not with :

- Groupbox (groupbox text doesn't change but children does)
- Combobox

I have tried in another application and it is the same.

Here is the result:

- Before color change: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhgE8.png)
- After color change: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9Kyu.png)

Why? How to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: For the ForeColor, you would have to set the Text property to blank and place a Label in the top corner instead.

Comment: That means that I have to do it for each Group box of my application... or make a new control.... great ! Also, if I change the forecolor of the groupbox itself, it works properly so, in the worst case I will have to do that so it is for the combobox but it is really not a great solution.

Comment: `Winform` is generally not focused on UI and in it it is hard to manipulate things like this. For this to work you would need to extends custom control from combobox and write drawing yourself, or cheat just like @LarsTech by placing label over it, or if you care that much about UI start building your app in WPF.

Comment: Well... thanks for the answer I guess. I must say I am disappointed. I thank you for your answer. It's sad that Microsoft is not able to implements that or fix it after sooo many years. I know that WPF is so much better for designing and much more unfortunately I am stuck with WinForm for now.
I guess the forecolor of my application will remain black because I will not make "cheat" like that just for beauty.